# WinDbg lmv command not working

Tags: windows, debugging, drivers

I'm using WinDbg with an administrator account on a VMWare virtual machine of Windows Server 2003 x64 machine. I'm debugging the local kernel with lkd (Kernel Debug -> Local Kernel).  I'm trying to view all the modules loaded in the kernel, but lmv (and the other lm commands) won't show anything but ntkrnlpa.exe loaded (and other `Unloaded modules:`). I've enabled kernel debugging using `bootcfg /debug ON /ID 1`

Is this a limitation of lkd? Because I can't see any information related to lm commands in the official documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I'm not able to simply comment.

Can you run "bcdedit" and check if the current boot config file has DEBUG set to YES?

If not, please run bcdedit /set debug {Default} on and restart, then try again.

Comment: Can't run bcdedit, because I'm on a Windows Server 2003 machine. I've used bootcfg to enable debug, as I said in the description.

Comment: So I have never used lkd, I can't tell you if this is supported. I have two ideas of what the issue might be: (a) lkd does not support the command. You should try enabling remote debugging in that case, though there might be a limitation with the OS you have installed. I don't know if net debugging was around for server 2003. You will also have to edit the bcd file using bcdedit, which you said you can't directly. But there might still be a bcd file on the VM you can copy to the host edit, then do the bcdedit /store bcfile /dbgsetting ... and bcdedit /store bcfile /debug on and copy it back.

Comment: Alternatively, if it is supported maybe you simply do not have this extension loaded. Look up the .load command in the documentation to check if you can copy it into the guest os and .load the dll containing the lmv command